# Register Controller from plugin Dll in NetCore 3 Preview 6

Tags: c#, api, plugins

I've just upgrade my ASP web API project from .Net core 2.2 to 3.0. I was using

```
var assembly = AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromAssemblyPath(pluginDll);
foreach(var type in assembly.GetTypes())
{
    if (typeof(Controller).IsAssignableFrom(assembly.GetType(type.FullName)))
    {
        this._logger.LogDebug(" + Controller: " + type.FullName);
        services.AddMvc().AddApplicationPart(assembly).AddControllersAsServices();
    }
}
```

previously to register the controllers as serviceses.

After the upgrade to 3.0 the controller is not registerted or the api will not find them.

so no endpoint is created.

Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: A Net application looks for dlls in two places. 1) The Windows Operating System 2) The application bin folder.First check old project to see if dll is in the bin folder.When in the bin folder I do not recommend manually putting any files into the bin folder because they can easily get deleted.Always add object to project by using the option add existing item.Then browse to where the source is located or put object in project folder where other cs source files are located.  After adding item go to Solution Explorer and right click on object.  Select one of the Copy options (Always or If newer).